# Setting default printer for the System user in Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012

Is there a way to set the default printer for the SYSTEM user?

Or, alternatively is there a way to set the default printer for ALL users of the server?

I am a C# \ SQL Server Developer by trade, so this stuff is beyond me a bit, and GOOGLE hasn't been of much use.  ( all old as dirt posts, nothing specific to 2012 )

**Basic Use Case:**

If I log in as a standard user, I can look at the list of printers and then right click on one of the printers and set it as my default.

Rather than doing that for each user on the server, is there a way to set the default printer for all users?

Or - specifically is there a way to set the default printer for the SYSTEM account?

Comment: What do you mean by "to set the default printer for the SYSTEM USER"? Could you please provide use case

Comment: @JevgenijMartynenko Updated my question.

Comment: Can you explain the context of what you are looking to do? The only case I can think is maybe a system service sending a scheduled print job.

Comment: I have a task that runs as the system account but for some reason my application cannot switch the printer so if I could just set the printer to the default.

Comment: Trying to print from the system account seems like such a bad idea.  You are trying to use one of the more notoriously bad things (printer drivers) in the context of the most privileged account on your system.  Sounds like a recipe for an unstable system and possibly some kind of way for a security compromise.

Comment: @Zoredache Our systems team set up a failover system for simple task programs.  The catch is for the tasks to fail over from one server to the other the system account has to be the one executing the task.  ( again I am not a guru here )

Comment: Using Registry:
Setting the default printer for all users involves modifying the Windows registry for each user profile. This is a more advanced method and should be done with caution.
Here's a basic example:
Open the registry editor (regedit.exe).
Navigate to HKEY_USERS.
For each subkey (representing a user), navigate to Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows and change or set the Device value to the desired default printer.
For the SYSTEM account, you would typically target the .DEFAULT profile, i.e., HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\....

Comment: Using PowerShell:
PowerShell can be a powerful way to automate these tasks, especially if you have many users.

# This sets the default printer for the current user
$printerName = "Your Printer Name"
(New-Object -ComObject WScript.Network).SetDefaultPrinter($printerName)

Comment: Using C#:
Since you mentioned you're a C# developer, you could also make use of the System.Management namespace to query and set default printers. You would need to run the code with administrative privileges.

Answer (score 0):

To set default printer for users logging on workstations or servers, you can use the following:

1. Group Policy if you have AD domain
2. User logon scripts as an alternative to #1

n.2 works in case of a stand-alone server too (without AD domain)

In case SYSTEM user you could use the same logon script. 
Just run it from SYSTEM account (e.g. via Task Manager or custom service).

Here is how you add default printer via VBScript:

```
Dim objNetwork, strUNCPrinter
strUNCPrinter = "\\printserver\HP LaserJet 1100"
Set objNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network") 
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection strUNCPrinter
objNetwork.SetDefaultPrinter strUNCPrinter
```

Save this to ***.vbs** file and run using **cscript.exe scriptfile.vbs**

Note: There are tons of samples on the web for adding printers using other scripting languages, if you prefer PowerShell or JScript

Comment: Where can I find such a User Logon Script?  Will this work for the SYSTEM user which does not have a logon?

Comment: How are you going to print a the system user? If you are running Jobs as system, why not call them from a user context? Though to provide a solution (that I have not tested) you can use PSEXEC with the -s flag to impersonate the system and run the following command RUNDLL32 PRINTUI.DLL,PrintUIEntry /y /n "Your_printer_name"

Comment: @MisterPositive updated my answer

Comment: @JevgenijMartynenko I will look at a power shell solution similar to this and see if it will work for my situation.